BLDC motor not working
I am attempting to connect a BLDC motor to a motor controller (24 V, 16 A), but I am unable to get the motor to start. The connection follows the configuration outlined in the accompanying image. In place of a throttle, I am using a 10 kΩ potentiometer. Despite adjusting the potentiometer and connecting the learning wire, the motor remains unresponsive.
Could you advise if there are any critical steps or considerations I may be overlooking?


Check windings by measuring resistance using multimeter, each winding should have equal resistance, also try to make connection as per directionwise.

Check wiring, especially the Hall Effect sensor. Do you see a voltage on the pot?

Is the motor controller pre-configured to drive the BLDC motor, or did you have to program the motor controller? To help get an answer can you edit the question to include the links to the datasheets for for the motor and controller.

Component part number and links would help greatly. || Q1 Is the original throttle pot 10K ?
